# Is it okay to ask one potential employer to match the base salary of another?

Tags: salary, job-offer, negotiation

I currently have two offers from tech companies, **A** and **B**

I would prefer **A** over **B** because I believe it is a better place to work, but **B** is offering me around **25k** more than **A**.

I have not been in this situation before, but would it be okay for me to email **A** something like:

***"I am really excited about your offer. However, I do have another position that is offering a little more compensation. Would you be able to match this? details of compensation from B...."***

I don't particularly think this is that uncommon, but if **A** asks proof to see **B's** compensation, is it **okay for me to share the offer letter from B?**

I can understand from **A's** perspective, they just want to make sure I really do have a higher offer.

I have read that usually its not a good idea to share job letters between different companies, but in the case for something like this, would it be appropriate?

Would it also be appropriate for me to share the **name** of the other company (these companies are essentially both in the same sector)

Thank you

Comment: If A doesn't trust you enough to take you at your word, is that really a company you want to work for? They don't need proof. Either they are willing to pay you what you ask, or they risk you walk away.

Comment: Well I haven't actually sent out an email yet, but A and B are both well known tech companies, so I don't doubt the trust aspect. I just want to know that if they do require an offer letter, if I should be giving it or not. 25k more is a big jump so just wanted to know the best course of action from my side

Comment: 1. This is an indication of a lack of trust and good faith on their part. 2. This is an indication that they want to give you a low-ball offer. 3. This would make me respond in the negative to their offer. "Thanks, but no thanks."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I determine a reasonable salary to ask for?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/896/how-can-i-determine-a-reasonable-salary-to-ask-for)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sharing competing offer letter marked as 'confidential'](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/170977/sharing-competing-offer-letter-marked-as-confidential?rq=1)

Comment: It's difficult to judge how big a difference 25k is without a baseline, currency, and time unit.

Answer (score 9):

> Is it okay to ask one potential employer to match the base salary of another?

It is OK to ask for more money if you feel that the value that you will provide for the company is worth the extra money.  This is part of a normal negotiation before accepting an offer.  You need to understand, however, that if you ask for an unreasonable (in their eyes) amount, they may simply remove you from consideration.  You should also be ready to walk away if the company is unwilling to budge.

I would leave company B out of it.  Explicitly mentioning company B or showing them their offer letter could backfire and cause you to lose both offers.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation, share the name of the company but NOT the offer letter. The intro to your e-mail is fine.