# Counter offer again after receiving another offer

Tags: job-search, negotiation

I received an offer letter from company A and counter offered with a higher salary which they accepted.
Later, I received an offer letter from company B that was substantially better than company A. I have signed neither offer letters.

I would prefer to work for company A, though working at B would be acceptable. Is there a way to tactfully ask company A if they would be willing to make their offer more in line with company B, or has that opportunity passed. If relevant, these are tech fields and this is my first job out of college.

Comment: You have leverage. Use it. If they want to lock you in, they have to get you to sign a contract. No contract. No deal. No one can promise you company A won't balk, but at least you'll have an offer from company B, and may be you'll have time to get a third offer from somewhere else.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it okay to ask one potential employer to match the base salary of another?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/171230/is-it-okay-to-ask-one-potential-employer-to-match-the-base-salary-of-another)

Comment: The question here would seem to be specifically, "Is there a way to tactfully ask...."  I have attempted to answer that.

Comment: You are correct, that was the actual question haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Congrats!

If you **really must do this**, consider taking the "super-honest and open" approach.  Hence, email Company A saying

> Dear Steve, unfortunately I have bad news. Thank you so much for your offer, but, believe it or not SuperCorp in Chiacgo just offered me a huge $XYZ,PQR salary to work there.  As you know Steve I genuinely wanted to work for ACorp and I far prefer ACorp to SuperCorp! However as you can imagine it's not possible for me to turn down $XYZ,PQR at this stage in my career and life! I just wanted to thank you again so much for the amazing chance to be considered by ACorp!  Kindly, etc.

In the *incredibly unlikely* chance that ACorp will make an even higher offer, they have the info.  As everyone has said, it's incredibly unlikely you will get yet-another offer.

I would say,

> If relevant, these are tech fields and this is my first job out of college

Don't worry too much, as it is unlikely that anyone will hate on you over this; people understand someone starting their career.  Maybe in the future you can swing back to ACorp.  You won't be burning any bridges if you take the "super honest, Gomer Pyle" approach to letting them know.

And by the way

(1) Obviously **absolutely wrap up and secure the job at SuperCorp so it is completely, totally locked in**

(2) After (1), let ACorp know promptly.

Enjoy!

Comment: Response is generally good, but the company making the counteroffer should probably not be named.

Answer (score 5):

> or has that opportunity passed.

It makes it less likely to succeed as they have already accepted one raise on their original offer. So the implication is that it's acceptable.

You can always try though, negotiation isn't finished until a contract is signed.